# What are the available datatypes for 'dtype' with NumPy's loadtxt() an genfromtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

What are the available [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) for importing table data with varying datatypes, and what are the available abbreviations for the use (e.g. **i32** for integer)?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660612/numpy-using-loadtxt-or-genfromtxt-to-read-a-ragged-structure) demonstrates the use of conditions, which I was curious if somebody might elaborate on.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in

Comment: Similar to this answer related to pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45063514/911945

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In addition to `np.sctypeDict`, there are these variables:

```
In [141]: np.typecodes
Out[141]: 
{'All': '?bhilqpBHILQPefdgFDGSUVOMm',
 'AllFloat': 'efdgFDG',
 'AllInteger': 'bBhHiIlLqQpP',
 'Character': 'c',
 'Complex': 'FDG',
 'Datetime': 'Mm',
 'Float': 'efdg',
 'Integer': 'bhilqp',
 'UnsignedInteger': 'BHILQP'}

In [143]: np.sctypes
Out[143]: 
{'complex': [numpy.complex64, numpy.complex128, numpy.complex192],
 'float': [numpy.float16, numpy.float32, numpy.float64, numpy.float96],
 'int': [numpy.int8, numpy.int16, numpy.int32, numpy.int32, numpy.int64],
 'others': [bool, object, str, unicode, numpy.void],
 'uint': [numpy.uint8, numpy.uint16, numpy.uint32, numpy.uint32, numpy.uint64]}
```

Answer (score 7):

Generic info about `dtypes`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in

> In NumPy, there are 24 new fundamental Python types to describe different types of scalars. These type descriptors are mostly based on the types available in the C language that CPython is written in, with several additional types compatible with Python’s types.

And what I didn't realise, is:

> The C-like names are associated with character codes, which are shown in the table. Use of the character codes, however, is discouraged.

I doubt the `numpy` code/doc base is going anyway anytime soon, so that says it all I guess!

Comment: +1 (Although conceivably, the `numpy` doc base could move away from `docs.scipy.org` without actually going away, as the [`numpy` top-level page](http://numpy.scipy.org) recently moved away…)

Comment: @abarnert I just learnt something new as well looking that page up - just going to put that in an edit

Comment: Ironic, scipy.org is offline today

Answer (score 3):

`for k, v in np.sctypeDict.iteritems(): print '{0:14s} : {1:40s}'.format(str(k), v)`

```
Q              : <type 'numpy.uint64'>      
U              : <type 'numpy.unicode_'>
a              : <type 'numpy.string_'>
```

etc.