# dtypes. Difference between S1 and S2 in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of strings:

```
In [51]: r['Z']
Out[51]: 
array(['0', '0', '0', ..., '0', '0', '0'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [52]: r['Y']                                                                                                                
Out[52]: 
array(['X0', 'X0', 'X0', ..., 'X0', 'X1', 'X1'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

What is the difference between S1 and S2? Is it just that they hold entries of different length?

What if my arrays have strings of **different lengths**?

Where can I find a list of all possible dtypes and what they mean?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See the [`dtypes` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

The `|S1` and `|S2` strings are data type descriptors; the first means the array holds strings of length 1, the second of length 2. The `|` pipe symbol is the [byteorder flag](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html#numpy.dtype.byteorder); in this case there is no byte order flag needed, so it's set to `|`, meaning not applicable.

Comment: I thought this rang a bell - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997087/what-are-the-available-datatypes-for-dtype-with-numpys-loadtxt-an-genfromtxt

Comment: Thanks! What would happen if my arrays had strings of different lengths? Is there a special S type for that?

Comment: @user273158: Arrays can *only* contain fixed length items; variable-length strings are not supported, not as `S` anyway. You can store object references (`dtype('O')`) where the objects *can be* Python strings, though.

Answer (score 4):

For storing strings of variable length in a numpy array you could store them as python objects.  For example:

```
In [456]: x=np.array(('abagd','ds','asdfasdf'),dtype=np.object_)

In [457]: x[0]
Out[457]: 'abagd'

In [459]: map(len,x)
Out[459]: [5, 2, 8]

In [460]: x[1]=='ds'
Out[460]: True

In [461]: x
Out[461]: array([abagd, ds, asdfasdf], dtype=object)

In [462]: str(x)
Out[462]: '[abagd ds asdfasdf]'

In [463]: x.tolist()
Out[463]: ['abagd', 'ds', 'asdfasdf']

In [464]: map(type,x)
Out[464]: [str, str, str]
```