# dtype argument in numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = StringIO("1,1.3,abcde")
>>> data = np.genfromtxt(
...     s,
...     dtype=[('myint','i8'), ('myfloat','f8'), ('mystring','S5')],
...     delimiter=",")
>>> data
array((1, 1.3, 'abcde'),
      dtype=[('myint', '<i8'), ('myfloat', '<f8'), ('mystring', '|S5')])
```

I am unable to understand what `dtype="i8,f8,|S5"` stands for.
I can make out that **i** is an integer, **f** is the float and **s** is the string but what is 8 in i8? I first understood it for bytes but how can then s5 be possible?

I understand that `dtype` helps to specify the data type so that we can read from CSV file but can someone give some insight on data types

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Comment: "i8,f8,|S5" is a short hand for the full dtype that your `data` display shows.  `<i8` is an 8 bytes (64 bit) integer, `<f8` is the nomal `float64`.  `S5` is a 5 character bytestring.  Look at `data['myint'].dtype`, the dtype of the first field in isolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8 in `i8` or `f8` is the number of bytes. There are several different ways to express the same [datatype in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html). The strings you see from `np.genfromtxt` are in the compact format. The `<` or `>` sign in front mean little or big endian (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)), followed by `i` for integer or `f` for float/double, and the number of bytes.

The longer datatype names have the size *in bits instead of bytes*, meaning that `i8` is `int64`, `f4` is `float32` and so on. E.g.:

```
>>> np.dtype('i8')
dtype('int64')
>>> np.dtype('f4')
dtype('float32')
```

By default these are all little endian. If you want big endian, as far as I know, `np.dtype` does not return the long form:

```
>>> np.dtype('>c16')
dtype('>c16')
```

Strings are a special datatype, and the number means the maximum number of string characters. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790130/dtypes-difference-between-s1-and-s2-in-python) for more details.