# MemoryError on running np.genfromtxt()

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a csv file which contains a matrix of around 18000x18000. The file itself is a little over 6GB. When I run

```
simData = np.genfromtxt(FileName, ",");
```

I get a "MemoryError" after it has run for a few minutes.

Any way around this?

Comment: Look here, can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027030/dtype-argument-in-numpy-genfromtxt

Comment: How did you create it?

Comment: What kind values does this contain?  flats, ints ?

Comment: I would assume that your RAM is not sufficient. The question has already been answered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956832/python-out-of-memory-on-large-csv-file-numpy.

Comment: contains floats

Comment: What's the dtype? Can you fit in RAM a matrix of that type (with zeroes for instance)? If yes, first, create the matrix, then load by batch with your own code and not `numpy.genfromtxt` which can be RAM hungry for large files.

Comment: loadtxt is the answer