# What do '|' and '<' mean in a numpy's type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numpy

Say I create the following numpy arrays of strings:

```
>>> np.array(['1.12', '-9.2', '42'], dtype=np.string_)
array([b'1.12', b'-9.2', b'42'], dtype='|S4')
>>> np.array(['1.12', '-9.2', '42'])
array(['1.12', '-9.2', '42'], dtype='<U4')
```

What do the types `'|S4'` and `'<U4'` mean? What is the size of a character with each?

Comment: And about [pipe sign here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790130/dtypes-difference-between-s1-and-s2-in-python)

Comment: those are short names for data types, you get more detail in following link https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 1):

These are [byte order flags](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html#numpy.dtype.byteorder). `<` is a "little endian" and `|` is "not applicable"

The `<` means:

> When storing a multi-byte value in memory as a sequence of bytes, the
>   sequence addresses/sends/stores the least significant byte first
>   (lowest address) and the most significant byte last (highest address).
>   Common in x86 processors.

Comment: How am I supposed to use that information (endianness) ?

Comment: ('>')Big Endian Byte Order: The most significant byte (the "big end") of the data is placed at the byte with the lowest address. The rest of the data is placed in order in the next three bytes in memory.

('<')Little Endian Byte Order: The least significant byte (the "little end") of the data is placed at the byte with the lowest address. The rest of the data is placed in order in the next three bytes in memory.