# Getting Nan, Infinite error in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am running few ml algos from sklearn. But for all those I am getting the following error

```
/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric)
    448     else:
    449         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 450         _assert_all_finite(y)
    451     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':
    452         y = y.astype(np.float64)

/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in _assert_all_finite(X)
     50             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     51         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
---> 52                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
     53 
     54 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

Please note that my design matrix has no nan or infinite value. Here is what I did to check:

```
np.isfinite(X_cohort_pr).all()
Out[259]:
True

X.isnull().any().any()
Out[261]:
False
```

So if you see my data matrix has no null or infinite values. then why I am getting this error and how to resolve this?. This has taken me more than 8 hours in debugging it.Please help

EDIT2:

Here is the first five rows of the data matrix. It has total 800K rows and some 180 odd features.

```
array([[ 1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    , -0.2637,  1.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.012 , -0.012 ,  0.    , -0.0028,
        -0.0108,  0.    , -0.0111, -0.0135,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.0034,
        -0.0027, -0.0725, -0.0673, -0.0625, -0.0582, -0.0065, -0.057 ,
        -0.0809, -0.355 ],
       [ 1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.2413,  1.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.012 , -0.012 ,  0.    , -0.0028,
        -0.0108,  0.    , -0.0111, -0.0135,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.0034,
        -0.0027, -0.0718, -0.0673, -0.0625, -0.0582, -0.0065, -0.057 ,
        -0.0809,  0.1579],
       [ 1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.1688,  1.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.012 , -0.012 ,  0.    , -0.0028,
        -0.0108,  0.    , -0.0111, -0.0135,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.0034,
        -0.0027, -0.0725, -0.0673, -0.0625, -0.0582, -0.0065, -0.057 ,
        -0.0809,  0.1642],
       [ 1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.2462,  1.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.012 , -0.012 ,  0.    , -0.0028,
        -0.0108,  0.    , -0.0111, -0.0135,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0004,
        -0.0012, -0.069 , -0.0673, -0.0618, -0.0582, -0.0065, -0.057 ,
        -0.0809,  0.1713],
       [ 1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,
         1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.1273,  1.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.012 , -0.012 ,  0.    , -0.0028,
        -0.0108,  0.    , -0.0111, -0.0135,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,
         0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0037,
        -0.0023, -0.0633, -0.0673, -0.0625, -0.0582, -0.0065, -0.057 ,
        -0.0809,  0.1713]])
```

Also I have seen one I run SVM, then I get the same Nan, Inf error but it also prints some values as below. Again, there are no NaN anywhere. I have checked it completely. Still I don't know why it is throwing those values.

```
_unique_labels = _FN_UNIQUE_LABELS.get(label_type, None)
    105     if not _unique_labels:
--> 106         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % ys)
    107 
    108     ys_labels = set(chain.from_iterable(_unique_labels(y) for y in ys))

ValueError: Unknown label type: 117456     0
117457     0
117458     0
117459     0
117460     0
117461     0
117462     0
117463     0
117464     0
117465     0
117466     2
117467     0
117468     0
117469     0
117470   NaN
117471     0
117472   NaN
117473     3
117474     0
117475   NaN
117476     0
117477   NaN
117478     6
117479     0
117480     0
117481   NaN
117482   NaN
117483     0
117484   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional case you're not checking: the **cast to np.float64**

It is possible that if you are using a higher precision data type, that the cast down renders a very big number as infinity; when you check the data in its original form, it merrily reports a finite number.

I can't be positive about your exact problem, but here is one way to produce your error: please provide a minimal reproducible example if you want more help. After 8 hours of debugging, I'm sure you have such an example :)

```
a = np.array([1e100],dtype=np.float128)
# 1e100 still fits within 64 bits. It's not trivial to
# instantiate an array with that large a number without
# doing arithmetic at some point
a *= a 
# make it EVEN BIGGER!!! (we're at 1e400 for those keeping track)
a *= a 
np.isfinite(a) # prints True: Check 
np.isfinite(a.astype(np.float64)) # prints... False. :(
```

To see if this is a case, just check the data type going into the procedure. It's possible you found such  huge value if your were reading from file or doing some arithmetic processing. You're biggest value in 64 bits is [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double) but there are [plenty of data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997087/what-are-the-available-datatypes-for-dtype-with-numpys-loadtxt-an-genfromtxt) to accommodate that value in numpy, as with standard infinite precision integers in python, anything's possible!

In the future, the debugging procedure might be to extract or comment out each conditional before that ValueError and print the data right before hand. You should be able to see *exactly* where the data goes amok. This process is muddled a little since your using external packages, but you can still get the source and test it this way if you've lost so many hours

Comment: What is a minimum reproducible example according to you? I can share some

Comment: The smallest amount of code that I can copy and paste into a text file and then run with my favourite python build and get the exact same error you get. Then I can know for sure what the issue is (or know that I don't know)

Comment: My original data has only int64 and float64 as the datatypes. So I don't think there is any value getting cast down. If there was any variable which had data type as float128 then that could have been a problem. Right?. With all already float64, do you think there is something else going on here?

Comment: If the data type of the original array is 64 bit it should not have been able to store anything larger than 64 bits. Try putting print statements before the exception gets raised to isolate the problem an report back, or provide some data I can reproduce the problem with (like I did in my code snippit in the answer)

Comment: I don't think numpy has float128. So I can't go beyond float64. Any idea how to convert to higher data type?

Comment: Pls check Edit 2. I provided first few rows of data and another error output

Comment: Okay so that's great, good additional info. The first error message related to X input and the second to Y input; are you sure that you're using them correctly? Do you understand the correct inputs for an SVM (I don't mean to be condescending, I'm just double checking). E.g., have you gotten the svm to work with simple sample data? That might be a very helpful first step

Comment: Thanks for asking. No I very well know SVM. I work on machine learning and I have used SVM in the past on various kinds of dataset. It says some issues with Y variable while my Y variables is a 6 class label. That's it. No Nan.