# What is the idiomatic way of casting to float using `astype(...)` in Pandas DataFrame/Series (and how about NumPy)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

I've tested the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1.0','2.0','3.0']})
print(df['x'].astype(float).dtype)
print(df['x'].astype('float').dtype)
print(df['x'].astype('float64').dtype)
print(df['x'].astype(np.float).dtype)
print(df['x'].astype(np.float64).dtype)
print(df['x'].astype('double').dtype)
print(df['x'].astype('single').dtype)
print(df['x'].astype('f').dtype)
```

All produce Pandas Series of dtype `float64` except the last two which produces `float32`:

```
float64
float64
float64
float64
float64
float64
float32
float32
```

Seeing as Python is supposed to have one "pythonic" way of doing things, what is the idiomatic way to create a float Series in Pandas (given that I don't really care what flavor of float it is)? Is this the same with NumPy?

I'm using Pandas 0.19.2 with a new-ish version of Python 3.

Comment: This is subjective. It would depend on how many characters you wish to type out and how much precision you need.

Answer (score 3):

IMO the most Pandaic way of casting series to numeric dtypes would be using of [pd.to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method, which can take care of those elements, that can't be casted to `float`:

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1.0','2.0','3.0', 'blah']})

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
      x
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3  blah

In [15]: df.dtypes
Out[15]:
x    object
dtype: object

In [16]: df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'], errors='coerce')

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
     x
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  NaN

In [18]: df.dtypes
Out[18]:
x    float64
dtype: object
```

Beside that we can make use of explicit downcasting:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1.0','2.0','3.0']})

In [22]: pd.to_numeric(df['x'], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
Out[22]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: x, dtype: int8
```

NOTE: [pd.to_numeric was added in Pandas 0.17.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements). If you have older version you can use [`df.convert_objects` which is deprecated in modern Pandas versions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html)

Comment: Looks good. Will accept later today, if nothing miraculous better comes along.

Comment: Note: `pd.to_numeric(...)` was introduced in version 0.17 of Pandas. Just as a heads up to anybody who's stuck at lower versions.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen, good point! I've added it to the answer

Comment: Much better than my answer (-:

Comment: @piRSquared, i think our answers complement each other :)

Answer (score 2):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

From [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

This is an opinion and philosophy. It is not set in stone. I wouldn't get hung up about it if there appears to be several viable options.

Comment: Not really hung up on it. But this did actually cause an issue at our office, as I used `astype(float)` which made a reviewer think I was casting to the native python float.

Comment: `numpy` has expanded the number of data types significantly compared to base Python, and provided many synonyms, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997087/what-are-the-available-datatypes-for-dtype-with-numpys-loadtxt-an-genfromtxt.  If readers confuse `dtypes` with native Python types then I'd favor the more explicit `numpy` labeling.

Comment: @hpaulj If not using `pd.to_numeric(...)` I would agree very much.