# How to get a list of all Numpy dtypes?

Tags: numpy

What is the command within Numpy's namespace that can be used for getting a list of all available dtypes/datatypes?

Comment: Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997087/what-are-the-available-datatypes-for-dtype-with-numpys-loadtxt-an-genfromtx?

Comment: @fuglede seems so, though when I did the search I could not find it...maybe because the title is restricting it specifically to loading text. The answers are very comprehensive though so thanks a lot!

Comment: In NumPy docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45063514/911945 (it works for NumPy as well).