# Python data type type codes comprehensive table or resource

Tags: python, numpy, types, printf

Today, and on several other occasions, I received an error like this:

`{TypeError}ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[us]') and dtype('O').`

On other days, I'd want to do some printf type command and be at a loss for which character stood for some obtuse data type (e.g. signed octal value).

I always had a hard time finding the definitions of what I now found to be called "type codes" or "Array-protocol type strings" in the first example and not to be confused with "printf-style String Formatting conversion characters" as in the later case, as they are single characters with string literal quotes, and thus Googling them is just a mess or trying to find synonyms for a word I didn't know. Maybe I'm just bad at RegEx and can't navigate man pages well enough, but I just wanted to throw up a possibly self answered question, in order to tag a bunch of synonyms for things I was trying to find and in the end landed on type code. I knew I was looking for python or numpy data types, and was scouring the internet for a `dtype('<M8[us]')` for the longest time so thought I'd help those who end up in a similar situation by providing a would-be online bookmark.

I had already read about various data types and this syntax in the past from various sources, knowing about the little-endian symbol '<', that '8' had something to do with the size, but would change depending on the dtype, but I had no idea what 'M' or '[us]' was defining. In my late night stupidity I looked over the numpy and python docs, but both for an earlier version than I had in my current env, and it looks like this 'M' did not appear until recently so I was left thinking all the tables in the docs were non-exhaustive and there was some other Unix or C based definition of all these type codes (which I still have not ruled out, but assume this is not the case now that I've found 'M' in my current Numpy version doc).

I will put the various resources that I've located regarding these various type codes in python and associated libraries here, but I'm sure there are plenty more, so would welcome others' additions/edits. I'll add all my links as an answer, and who knows, if others also found themselves in this situation, maybe I'll make a type code cheat sheet or something as a general resource online somewhere. Anyways, I think they'd be helpful to gather in a place tagged by a bunch of keywords that I was using trying to find them, to no avail like: python numpy data type shorthand definitions, python numpy dtype abbreviations, python array dtype codes, etc. If you have any other words that came to your mind when labeling these un-googleable terms, feel free to edit and add.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997087/what-are-the-available-datatypes-for-dtype-with-numpys-loadtxt-an-genfromtx

Comment: for `np.datetime64` look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: I'm not sure you should be conflating the Python print formats with `numpy` `dtypes`in the same question/answer.  They generally aren't used in the same context.  One exception, Python style '%' formatting is used in `np.savetxt`.

Comment: Regarding your initial error message. Identify the line and variables where the error occurs.  I suspect in this case you'll see that it involves `numpy` arrays that somehow represent dates.  The `M` marks a `np.datetime64` dtype (the other characters aren't significant in this context).  The `O` is `object`, possibly `datetime` objects that haven't been converted to `datetime64`.  Math involving both dtypes is quite restrictive.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for all the comments! Your linked post is similar to what I had been finding here and there (answers to single type code meanings, e.g. i32). I had not seen np.typecodes displayed like that nor, np.sctypeDict before. I might add that the later can be quite helpful as a quick way of finding any given code by calling it out like this ```np.sctypeDict['M']``` would provide tell you 'M' represents a datetime64 type. The former (np.typecodes) provides groupings, but I don't see an easy way to look up the differences between the various Integer types 'bhilqp' for example though.

Comment: I knew that printf and these data types are inherently different, but I was trying to link them for the sole purpose of making numpy type codes a searchable term linked to other known terms (as a way to get around being unable to search for single character literals in Google). Though fundamentally different, numpy type codes and printf interpreters looked similar (i.e. a single character literal standing for some data type), so searching for things like 'printf style data type characters numpy' was one method I was trying, without much luck. Hoping to give the next searcher an easier time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General notes:

- Make sure you are reading the doc for the right version of python, numpy, etc.
- The codes used depend on the use case (i.e. numpy array-protocol type strings are different than those used to define the types in general python arrays)
- Even worse, some of the same characters are used to mean different things depending on the use case ('b' and 'B' for example if you compare numpy and python arrays, or 'd' if comparing python printf and array codes).

[Numpy 1.17](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types): Array-protocol type strings and the 'M' type

[Python 3.8.0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting): printf conversion types

[Python 3.8.0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) Array type codes. Edit: This class is not used often, but just wanted here for comparative and exhaustive reference.

[Python 3.8.0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) string formatter "mini language" syntax, aka "presentation types"

I won't go to the trouble of reiterating the docs despite my answer being primarily links since I don't expect the docs to go down anytime soon, but for the main point of how I got here, 'M' stands for a datetime type in numpy and ['[us]'](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20type) was for microsecond resolution

Comment: I would drop that last Python `Array` codes link.  That module isn't used very much, especially if `numpy` is already available and being used.

Comment: Python3 tries to replace the `%` style of formatting with a `str.format()` syntax.  The letter codes are similar, but details differ: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: @hpaulj thanks again. I updated my answer to include your comments.